# Why MutationRecord[] is an array? (MutationObserve)

Tags: javascript, dom, mutation-observers

I am learning [MutationObserve](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#example), and I can get it almost, but the only one I confuse with is why the parameter needs an array.

The document said:

> [An **array** of MutationRecord objects, describing each change that occurred;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/MutationObserver#parameters)

I need a example which `mutationRecordList.length > 1`

```html
<h2 id="testNode" onclick="addTimeNode(this)">Click me!</h2>

<script>
  function addTimeNode(node) {
    const nodeP = document.createElement("p")
    const today = new Date()
    nodeP.innerText = [today.getHours(), today.getMinutes(), today.getSeconds()].join(":")
    node.append(nodeP)
  }

  (
    () => {
      window.onload = () => {
        const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationRecordList, observer)=>{
          if (mutationRecordList.length > 1){
            console.log("Thanks. This is what I want!") // 
          }
          console.log(observer.name)
          for(const mutation of mutationRecordList) {
            const target = mutation.target
            switch(mutation.type) {
              case "childList":
                console.log('A child node has been added or removed.')
                break
            }
            if (target.childNodes.length > 2) {
              observer.disconnect()
              console.log('disconnect observer')
            }
          }
        })
        observer.name = "test observer"
        observer.observe(document.getElementById('testNode'), {
          // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe#parameters
          childList: true,
        })
      }
    }
  )()
</script>
```

Comment: It always happens while the page is loading and you can see it if you attach the observer in an inline script at the beginning of html. It can also happen when there were a lot of separate DOM operations in the same event loop cycle.

Comment: Hi @WOxxOm, thanks for answering so quickly, and your comment is helpful. If you post the answer, I will upvote for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @wOxxOm, and I think below is a demo for a lot of separate DOM operations in the same event loop cycle.

```html
<h2 id="testNode" onclick="addTimeNode(this)">Click me!</h2>

<script>
  function addTimeNode(node) {
    const nodeP = document.createElement("p")
    const nodeP2 = document.createElement("p")
    nodeP.className = "test-add"
    nodeP2.className = "test-delete"
    const today = new Date()
    nodeP.innerText = [today.getHours(), today.getMinutes(), today.getSeconds()].join(":")
    node.append(nodeP, nodeP2)
    node.querySelector(`p[class="test-delete"]`).remove()
  }

  (
    () => {
      window.onload = () => {
        const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationRecordList, observer)=>{
          if (mutationRecordList.length > 1){
            console.log(`Thanks. This is what I want. length:${mutationRecordList.length}`) // 
          }
          console.log(observer.name)
          let i = 0
          for(const mutation of mutationRecordList) {
            console.log(`mutationRecordList[${i++}]`)
            const target = mutation.target
            switch(mutation.type) {
              case "childList":
                for (const node of mutation.addedNodes) {
                  console.log(`A child node has been added. className:${node.className}`)
                }

                for (const node of mutation.removedNodes) {
                  console.log(`A child node has been removed. className:${node.className}`)
                }
                break
            }
            if (target.childNodes.length > 2) {
              observer.disconnect()
              console.log('disconnect observer')
            }
          }
          console.log('----')
        })
        observer.name = "test observer"
        observer.observe(document.getElementById('testNode'), {
          // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe#parameters
          childList: true,
        })
      }
    }
  )()
</script>
```